# Getting the wildcard value of a command

Tags: shell, grep

In this problem the working directory looks like that:

```
├── xaa
├── xab
├── xac
├── xad
...
├── xan
├── xao
├── xap
├── xaq
├── xep
```

I tried to use this command to match any occurrence of the word "foo" in those files:

```bash
cat x* | grep foo
```

It gives me a match but not the filename where it comes from. If anyone has a tip it would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the following command:

##### Just the filename(s):

```
grep -l foo x*
```

##### Both filename(s) and match(es):

```
grep -H foo x*
```